# looking for grails front-end plugin

Tags: node.js, grails

I'm looking for the grails plugin which is for frontend.

Last time, I was in Java based project, and there was a maven plugin for frontend.

Link: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

It deals with nodejs, so I could use it with grunt, or gulp like that.

This time, I am in Grails based project, and looking for the plugin that is for same purpose.

However, as far as I know, there is no plugin for that.

Can anybody give me a solution?

The alternative one is to install Node.js in our server directly, but hope that there's another way.

Answer (score 2):

Grails 3 is using the Gradle build system, so you can use the gradle node plugin (`com.moowork.node`) to do this.

Here's an example of a build.gradle file (in the angular 2 profile for grails, but you can use it any way you'd like for your framework or front end)

https://github.com/grails-profiles/angular2/blob/master/skeleton/client/build.gradle

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how about for grails 2.4.3?

Comment: I'm not aware of any for grails 2. You may be able to create one yourself using the grails 2 build system.

Another option would be to use the example I provided as a separate project in the same directory, then at least it's all in java and encapsulated so you do not need to install node on every dev's machine.